# How to Block a Wifi-Router by MAC adress via terminal

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, mac-address

I Need a Little help.

Explain : i got in my Home a homespot/hotspot with „ Ssid: Vodafone homespot“.
This is a Service run by every Router from Vodafone where homespot sharing is active. There are 5 Networks with Same Ssid but with different MAC adresses

My Problem:

One of the Homespots Are too Slow AND sometimes have no Internet Connection AND it is the closesest to my Computer so linux Connect to These automaticly.
I Need to Block it via MAC adress or anything else. I just want Connect to a specify Mac adress to one of 5 Networks with Same ssid.

My Question to you:

Is there a Tool or Software to handle this ?? Is there a way to do this in the linux Terminal? Is it possible to make the Network settings that the Wireless Adapter ignore MAC adresses which i want to ignore??
I am fresh at Linux , so be Patient please with me

My OS : Linux Mint Xfce Edition (newest Version)
My Wifi Adapter: Realtek 8812bu

Comment: Why not just rename the the SSID and connect to it - `https://deviceguides.vodafone.co.uk/vodafone/mobile-wi-fi-r218-windows-10/connectivity/change-wi-fi-hotspot-name/` - ignore `Windows-10`

Comment: This is Not Working in germany . Vodafone offers a Little different homespot Service here. Homespot Service is Coded in firmware of the Router so you cant change it anyway but also very big big thank you from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual term you're looking for (MAC address of Wi-Fi access point) is "**B**SSID".

If Linux Mint uses NetworkManager for Wi-Fi, as far as I know, NM currently has no option to *block* a specific BSSID. So you'll need to specifically choose one to always use.

You can specify the exact BSSID that you *want* to use in the connection profile (for example, via GNOME Settings or via `nm-connection-editor` below):

[image]
[image]

The same parameter can be changed through `nmcli` as `802-11-wireless.bssid`:

```
nmcli con modify "My network" wifi.bssid AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

See also:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/833905/how-can-i-connect-to-a-specific-bssid